# Solving the equation $\sqrt[3]{x^2 + 15} = 2\sqrt[3]{x+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

In this equation
$$
  \sqrt[3]{x^2 + 15} = 2\sqrt[3]{x+1}
$$
if I try to put in the third exponent both sides and I get an equation with the roots 7 and 1.Are these roots the same for the first equation? I get they are by doing the proof but a program says it's only 1. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to provide more details about your problem. Who is "they" in "I get that they are doing the proof..."? What is the program you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I follow what you are saying.
$$
\sqrt[3]{x^2 + 15} = 2\sqrt[3]{x+1}
$$
You could cube both sides and get
$$
x^2 +15 = 8(x+1).
$$
So
$$
x^2 - 8x + 7 = 0.
$$
This indeed has the solutions $1$ and $7$. You can verify (if you want to be sure) that both of these two solutions are solutions to your equation. For example
$$
\sqrt[3]{7^2 + 15} = 4 = 2\sqrt[3]{7 + 1}.
$$

Comment: But, it's not a necessity, right?

Comment: @ANNALIA: What do you mean by a necessity?

Comment: If I want to get the right answer I don't need to do the proof, I suppose in this case

Comment: @ANNALIA: If you mean if it is necessary to check, then no it is not.

Comment: @ANNALIA: I don't understand. This is how you would (could) solve your equation.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just wanted to be sure I did it right